# Comparator issue when switching to Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator, java-6

I am moving from Java 6 to Java 8 and noticed something peculiar with the Comparator interface. Any insight to this would be very helpful.

When I switch to Java 8, the order of the object is being switched inside the “compare” method and the list sorting fails. I go back to java 6 and it works just fine. Here is a test case that fails for me with Java 8 and passes with Java 6.

```
public class ComparitorTest {

@Test
public void comparatorTest(){
    Record record1 = new Record("First", false);
    Record record2 = new Record("Second", true);
    List<Record> list = new ArrayList<Record>();

    list.add(record1);
    list.add(record2);


    final Comparator<Object> recordComparator = new Comparator<Object>()
            {
                public int compare( Object o1, Object o2 )
                {
                    Record r1 = (Record) o1;
                    Record r2 = (Record) o2;

                    Boolean isReadonly_R1 = r1.getIsReadOnly();
                    Boolean isReadOnly_R2 = r2.getIsReadOnly();

                if( isReadonly_R1.equals( Boolean.TRUE ) )
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                }
            };
            Collections.sort(list, recordComparator);

            assertEquals(list.get(0).name, "Second");
            assertEquals(list.get(1).name, "First");

}



class Record {
    boolean isReadOnly; 
    String name;

    public Record(String name, boolean value) {
        isReadOnly =value;
        this.name = name;
    }

     boolean getIsReadOnly() {
        return isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

}

Any insight you guys on this would be very helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `Comparator` isn't a valid `Comparator`.  It only looks at the first item to compare; it ignores the second item.  It is incapable of returning a negative number, which means that the first item can never be considered "less than" the second item.

The algorithm used to sort the list happened to work in Java 6 (it had a 50/50 chance, after all), but the algorithm must have changed between Java 6 and Java 8.

You will need to fix your `Comparator`'s logic according to [the `compare` method's contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-):

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Additionally, it doesn't need to be a `Comparator<Object>`.  Make it a `Comparator<Record>`, and the `compare` method can take `Record`s instead of `Object`s.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm changed. In Java 7 *TimSort* was introduced. There is also a system property which allows reverting to the old algorithm, but since fixing broken comparators should be preferred, I don’t waste time looking up the exact name of that property…

Answer (score 5):

Your comparator is utterly broken. If it has worked up to now it has been due to pure luck.

If you do `compare(a, b)` and `compare(b,a)`, then either

- `a` and `b` are equal and both calls return 0
- `a` and `b` are not equal, one call returns a positive number and the other a negative one.

But your comparator **never** returns a negative value. That breaks the `compare` contract. You are not setting an order relationship.

Another giveaway tip is that you are only using r1 to calculate the results...

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the existing answers I would add the following—coming to Java 8 you should drop the entirety of your custom Comparator implementation. Apparently you want to sort records so that all read-only records come first, then all writable ones. This is a one-liner in Java 8:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Record::getIsReadOnly).reverseOrder());
```